# Responsive video embeds within a flex parent

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, grid

I like using this CSS to make my YouTube embeds responsive while maintaining their aspect ratio:

```
.video {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

But I'd like to also list them out in a horizontal list that uses display: flex; so the list stays on one row without wrapping, regardless of how many videos are in the list.

Is this possible? I'm getting height stretch issues on my video items when doing this, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I stated flex parent in my question title, I was able to achieve what I was looking for with display: grid;

It does line wrap into two rows at a certain size due to the minmax 300px I declared below, but that can be removed.

```
.productVideosList {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 16px;
}

.productVideosList__item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.2%;
    height: 0;
}

.productVideosList__item iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```